# Rails - syntax error in controller for using 2 join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, join

I'm trying to deal with multiple join tables in employee's controller.

I have 2 join tables: http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/1cze8z4k/beziehungen.png

- employee -> position -> join table expected_qualifications -> skills
- employee -> join table current_qualifications -> skills

now I wrote into employee controller: 
`@employee = Employee.find(params[:id], :include => [{:position => { :expected_qualifications => :skill}, { :current_qualifications => skill}] )`

but there's a syntax error:

c:/src/script/system/app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting tASSOC

...urrent_qualifications => skill}] )

................................................^

First I have no idea what "tASSOC" is, google couldn't answer me this. But the more important thing: How to write this code so there won't be a syntax error anymore?

Answer (score 0):

tASSOC is the `=>` token.

You have code like this, which is not valid:

```
{ :a => :b, { :c => :d } }
```

You must specify a key for every value in a Hash.  You have only specified a key `:position`, which has a Hash as it's corresponding value.  The following stuff is not valid, since it doesn't have a key (or rather, the Ruby interpreter is seeing the second value in the Hash as being a key without a value... thus it is expecting `=>` to follow it).

EDIT | Note that:

```
{ :a => :b, { :c => :d } => :e }
```

would be syntactically valid, which is why Ruby is assuming that second nested Hash is actually a key.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm not into this syntax and I'm a really bloody beginner, so I can't follow you much, sorry for that! 
Are :a, :b, :c ... all different tables? I can't really transfer it to my case, sorry. 

Something like this?
`{ :current_qualifications => :skill, {:expected_qualifications => :skill} => :position}`


the part `{:position => { :expected_qualifications => :skill}}` already works perfectly, just when I want to add the rest, I come into trouble.

Comment: I'm avoiding commenting on tables etc, since the problem is your understanding of the language itself ;)  The syntax for a Hash is: `{key => value, key => value, key => value}` etc.  The key and value can be anything (String, Symbol, Array, Hash...), but they must always be paired together.  When you nest a set of curl braces inside a Hash, you're creating *another Hash*, so `{:a => {:b => :c}}` produces a 2-dimensional Hash, where `hash[:a][:b] == :c`. But `{:a => {:b => :c}, {:d => :e}}` will cause a parse error, since the `{:d => :e}` part is a single value (a Hash) with no paired key.

Comment: Yeah, I'm non-native-English-speaker and I guess I produce horrible sentences :P Sry! 
Thanks, I think I understood what you meant. So if I remove the curl braces which surround :d => :e, syntax must be right. I implemented it for my case, now there's just a name error `undefined local variable or method `current_qualifications' for #<Class:0x37cb3d8>`...

Comment: just wanted to notice that it worked now: 
`@employee = Employee.find(params[:id], :include => {:position => { :expected_qualifications => :skill}, :current_qualifications => :skill} )`